# Update SharePoint list when the word document content property data is changed by the user

Tags: list, sharepoint, ms-word, power-automate

I am trying to find a possible way to create a flow to read the word document content properties when the user makes a change. For example if the user update the cost in the document, the cost updated/changed value should reflect in the SharePoint list. I have done extensive search but wasn't successful. Hoping to see if anyone is aware of a possible solution.

Comment: There isn’t any trigger in Power Automate for Microsoft Word that can achieve this.

Comment: @Ethan is there a workaround for this process?

Comment: it would have to be the opposite. The user would have to enter information in the SP list and then the Word document would get populated